# Принцип работы PropertyInfo.GetValue()?

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Не могу понять работу метода `PropertyInfo.GetValue()`.

Мне было необходимо проверить все свойства объекта `customerOb` (см. код ниже) на `null` и вернуть `true` в случае успеха. Я это сделал, используя данный [пост](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22683141/2948684), но не могу понять это самое "как" все работает.

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }      
    public CustomerEdit CustomerEdit { get; set; }
} 

class Program
{        
    static void Main()
    {
        var custumerOb = new Customer();
        var isAllPropertiesNull = custumerOb.GetType()
                                            .GetProperties()
                                            .Select(pi => pi.GetValue(custumerOb))
                                            .All(p => p == null);
    }       
}
```

Значит:

```
custumerOb.GetType() - это понятно  

.GetProperties() - это понятно

.Select(pi => pi.GetValue(custumerOb)) - это НЕ понятно
```

Было бы понятно если `GetValue()` не принимал параметр:

```
.Select(pi => pi.GetValue())
```

А то мы как бы получаем очередное свойство `pi` и чтобы узнать его значение передаем в (его) метод `GetValue()` объект чьим свойством он является.

Я запутался. Объясните пожалуйста выражение `.Select(pi => pi.GetValue(custumerOb))`. Что конкретно тут происходит?

Comment: `pi` - это PropertyInfo, не привязанное к конкретному объекту, поэтому чтобы получить значение свойства у _конкретного_ объекта, нужно этот объект как-то обозначит. В данном случае, объект у которого берется свойство передается первым параметром.

Comment: Ну вы же разницу между классом и объектом знаете?
Вот чтобы проверить содержимое свойства нужен конкретный объект

Comment: Обратите внимание, что мы работаем не с самим объектом, а с его типом (объектом типа `Type`): `custumerOb.GetType()`, тоже самое если бы мы написали `typeof(Customer)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Сначала мы получаем **тип** объекта: `custumerOb.GetType()`.
Потом мы получаем все `properties`, описанные в этом типе: `GetProperties()`. Это вернет нам массив объектов класса `PropertyInfo`. Они относятся к описанию класса `Customer`, но не к экземпляру этого класса `customerOb`.
У класса `PropertyInfo` есть метод `GetValue`. Но мы же не можем просто получить значение свойства идя от описания класса, в котором описано это свойство. Мы должны сказать, значение свойства какого **экземпляра** этого класса мы хотим получить. Для этого мы и передаем в этот метод конкретный экземпляр класса: `customerOb`.

Comment: Добавьте еще про статические свойства.